# Get the index while looping

Tags: c#, .net, loops, datagridview, indexing

Is it possible to get the current index while looping?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
 {
     myValue = DGV.CurrentRow.Index + " " + DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
 }
```

But I have in output :

```
0 First
0 Second
0 ...
```

I want to get :

```
1 First
2 Second
3 ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that you are skipping the last row?

Comment: To add to answers below - DGV.CurrentRow represents the row containing the current cell, or null if there is no current cell. it would remain 0 and won't change just because you are iterating over all rows.

Comment: It's a bad idea to loop over the DGV anyway. Bind it to a proper datastructure.

Comment: You are not changing the CurrentRow in the loop, so why do you think it should be changing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
{
   myValue = (i + 1).ToString() + " " + DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

BTW: I'd prefer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
{
   myValue = String.Format("{0} {1}", i + 1, DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the index just `i+1` in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
myValue = (i+1) + " " + DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way also

```
for (int i = 1; i < DGV.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
     myValue = i.ToString() + " " + DGV.Rows[i-1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
 }
```